# QGIS on Mavericks

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, homebrew

I have been trying to install QGIS on Mavericks and I have failed. 
Prior to installing QGIS, I installed GDAL using homebrew. 
I also installed Numpy, SciPy and pyqt using the detailed instructions provided at: 
http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/

I modified my .bash_profile so that when I run `echo $PYTHONPATH`

I get `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:`

I tried first installing qgis running

```
brew install qgis --with-grass --with-postgis
```

and I get the error message

```
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libpng/1.5.17/lib'
make[3]: *** [libcairo.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/3526
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/23375
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/20522
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/23252
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/16361
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/18528
```

Then I also tried downloading the QGIS .dmg file from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis However, I get an error message each time I try opening Install QGIS.pkg saying that I need matplotlib that I already have!

Is anyone else also having problems installing QGIS on Mavericks? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Hello, to me its seems that QGIS isn't ready yet for Maverick. I only see installer for Snow Leopard and Mountain Lion at kyngchaos. On the main page he says: "I don't plan on upgrading to OS X Mavericks (10.9) soon".  regards

Comment: Wrong, read the text: "that my Lion builds work on Mavericks". No problem for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to mix different things:

1) You want to use the Homebrew version of QGIS:

- Everything must be installed by Homebrew as binaries and libraries in /usr/local/Cellar with symbolic links in /usr/local/bin, GDAL/OGR, QGIS, ....
- the Homebrew QGIS version uses the Homebrew Python version with modules in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
- All the Python modules you have installed (Numpy, SciPy pyqt...), works only with the Homebrew version of Python
- If it doesn't work, it is the problem of Homebrew (can find libpng library, for example)

2) you want to use the Kyngchaos's version of QGIS

- You should install his versions of the libraries ( [Unix Compatibility Frameworks (KyngChaos)](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) ) which are installed as Frameworks in /Library/Frameworks).
- The QGIS version uses the Apple Python with modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
- If you don't know Python you can download the Python modules at [Python Modules (KyngChaos)](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python)
- the installer examine whether there is a folder named "matplotlib" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. If not, no installation (even if matplotlib is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages)

3) if you want, you can also use the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) version of QGIS

- with the Python version of MacPorts (in /opt), and so on.

4) conclusions

So you have to choose between 2 solutions (Homebrew and Kyngchaos) without mixing them ( unless you know UNIX path manipulation very, very well ).

And the people using the Kyngchaos version do not experience any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I installed all the libraries and Python modules with Kingchaos to then install QGIS from Kingchaos and it worked.
Since I have tried all the previous steps with Homebrew, I guess there is a problem with the brew version of QGIS. Thank you for your explanations

Comment: Of note: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/99841/6725 for a currently important fix needed for the GDAL.framework Python setup. On fresh installs, this affects things like Processing plugin.