# Trying to install QGIS - missing 1.11 GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, osx

I just spent the last *n* hours working on this, and still haven't gotten anywhere, so I'll throw it to the group. I see that other people have asked about this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97904/snag-loading-gdal-1-11-for-qgis-2-2-on-a-mac) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80856/qgis-on-mavericks), and I'd be happy to take down this Q if that gets answered.

My specs:

- Mac 10.9.4
- Mavericks OS

I'm trying to install QGIS. I'm working with the [KyngChaos package](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). It gives me an error on installation, saying, "Failure: The GDAL 1.11 framework is required." I've since tried to `brew install gdal`, which installed the 1.10 framework. QGIS installation still fails. I then did `brew update`, and tried again (which seemed promising). Still fails. I then tried to follow [this guy's approach](http://blog.burhum.com/post/36080548777/getting-qgis-working-on-homebrew), and `brew install qgis`. This kept my Terminal busy for about 3-4 hours... and still failed. Though I *swear* I saw a green-fonted gdal library get installed in all that Terminal chatter.

FWIW, the `brew install qgis` gave me a slightly different error message:

```
[ 50%] Built target qgis_gui
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

No idea what this means. I'm trying to find gdal in my computer via the Terminal: mostly doing `which gdal -a`, though this doesn't return anything. So I'm not sure how to even check that GDAL 1.11 got installed.

Comment: I have no experience with MAC, but Kyngchaos offers a GDAL complete 1.11 package, which requires Apple's Java 6. I suggest to start with the latter, then the GDAL package (and Matplotlib), then QGIS. If it still fails, look out for an installation log.

Comment: try "gdalinfo --version" to know the installed version

Answer (score 5):

For QGIS on Mac, the Kyngchaos.com installer package is built against the GDAL_Complete installer framework from the same site, as is noted under [Requirements on the download page](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). It will **not** work with `gdal` from the Homebrew project.

If you want to go with a purely Homebrew approach, try the [OSGeo4Mac project](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac). First run `brew unlink qgis`, which is the outdated formula version in `homebrew/science`, then do run the following:

```
brew install osgeo/osgeo4mac/qgis-24
```

If you are on Mavericks and you're using the default HOMEBREW_PREFIX of `/usr/local`, `qgis-24` and several of its default dependencies will be installed via 'bottles,' i.e. pre-built binaries, instead of compiling from source code, saving you a huge amount of time. If you change the default build options for `qgis-24` to something else, then it will build from source again.

If you have any issues, please post them to the [OSGeo4Mac tracker](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues), instead of here.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting "No available formula with the name "osgeo/osgeo4mac/qgis-24" " then I realised that the OSGeo4Mac project was already in qgis-28 so I used that version instead.